# riding up to their bridle reins - meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Usage example with [a context](http://www.miamiherald.com/opinion/op-ed/article10647395.html):

> The Atocha bombings were brutal acts of terrorism, but as Ferré acknowledges, there were many atrocities in the Crusades as well. Crusade chroniclers reveled in the slaughter of the population of Jerusalem: One wrote of crusaders **riding up to their bridle reins** in blood at the Dome of the Rock and called the massacre a splendid judgment of God.

What does that exactly mean?

Comment: Compare: "I'm up to my neck in work today".  Riding through a river of blood that came all the way up to the horse's neck...

Comment: I "skipped" the close vote. I'm not sure if a learner will definitely be able to get this **completely** out of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly awkward placement of the modifiers, I would say.

Personally, I'd rewrite that as: *One wrote of crusaders **riding through blood** up to their bridle reins at the Dome of the Rock*

So, depending on how tightly the reins were being gripped, the image intended to be evoked is crusaders riding through blood, and the blood was like a river that came up to somewhere on the horse's neck. This is unlikely to be literally descriptive (though I could be wrong); I would be inclined to think it was a metaphor for crusaders riding down their targets, with gore and blood *spattering and soaking* them and their horses up to the horses' necks.

But this, arguably, may be why it's "riding up to their bridle reins in blood": the author is trying to get the blood-soaked image of riders with horses all gory and red up to their necks, *without* the metaphorical river of blood -- and failing to make the actual *sentence* parse perfectly. I'd treat this as an example of someone trying to evoke an image, and taking liberties with the language in a similar way to songs or poems.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a literary reference.  Historical sources, especially medieval and crusader chronicles are littered with biblical references.

A similar passage from the same event I found is a letter from Daibert, Archbishop of Pisa et. al. to Pope Urban II, written in September of 1099.

> Should you wish to learn what happened to the enemies we found inside, know that our horsemen rode knee-deep in Saracen blood in Solomon's Porch and in his Temple.

This is not possible, as the Dome of the Rock (Qubbat aṣ-Ṣakhra) and the plaza it sits on, which the writer calls Soloman's temple and porch, are above the city level and could not hold any fluid to that depth without submerging the city.

The passage alludes to a biblical verse, Revelation 14:20.

> They were trampled in the winepress outside the city, and blood flowed out of the press, rising as high as the horses' bridles...

Crusaders continuously drew parallels between their actions, the Old Testament, and Revelations.